# Copy SVN Repository

Tags: svn, import, repository, export

I have an SVN repo at a hosted SVN service which I need to move to our locally hosted SVN service. The host offers an export feature, which I've used. But how do I take that exported file and import it into a new repository?

EDIT

I tried using svnadmin load, but got an error message:

```
% svnadmin load . < ~/ss2_14066_rev36
svnadmin: Malformed dumpfile header
```

The service I'm exporting from is http://beanstalkapp.com, and their [help page for export](http://help.beanstalkapp.com/kb/managing-repositories/can-i-export-my-repository) says this exported file can be reimported to another svn server. Is this possibly a server version mismatch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the export was created using `svnadmin dump` you can import it into a new, empty repository using

```
# cd /path/to/new/repo
# svnadmin load . < /path/to/dumpfile
```

Comment: I get:

svnadmin: Malformed dumpfile header

I'm checking with the host to see what format this export is, exactly...

Comment: Yeah, if svnadmin doesn’t like it you should check back with your hosting service about what you’re supposed to do with the file.

Comment: Thanks, looking at the file, something seems off. Marking this answer as correct as it would work if.. you know.. the file worked. :P

Comment: svn dump files are delicate things. make sure it's not been edited with a text editor or any other programm for the matter.

Comment: @Ian If the dump file is zipped, unzip it and then run the load command

Answer (score 4):

If your hosting provider uses Subversion 1.4 or later you can also use svnsync to create a copy from the repository.

See [The Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.c.copy-revprops.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that it's not a dumpfile but rather a tar.gz of the repository itself?

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
/path/to/dumpfile
```

has to be an absolute path to a (.dmp) FILE that can be streamed back to the svnadmin load command, not just a directory location.